# how to delete a specific line from a file starting a string in php

Tags: php

I have a text file names data.dat containing space separated strings on each line. I want to delete a whole line starting with a specific from it, Please provide tested php code for it. I'm using php 5.4+

File Contents :

```
abc samle sample
this abc sample
xyz test sample sample
```

For example, I have `$str="this"`. So in this case I want to delete 2nd line, For general that could occur at first line or middle or end. Main thing is I dont want any empty line. So new file should be

```
abc samle sample
xyz test sample sample
```

Comment: This looks like your asking us to complete your homework for you :(

Comment: The principle here is that you provide the code and we help you to get it working.

Comment: First go through the similar questions like given and then upload your code if you find an error...
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5712878/how-to-delete-a-line-from-the-file-with-php

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/q/3642222/2943403

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try with this:

```
<?php
    $f = "data.dat";

    $term = "this";

    $arr = file($f);

    foreach ($arr as $key=> $line) {

        //removing the line
        if(stristr($line,$term)!== false){unset($arr[$key]);break;}
    }

    //reindexing array
    $arr = array_values($arr);

    //writing to file
    file_put_contents($f, implode($arr));
?>
```

Comment: Thanks, I did this 

`<?php $arr = file("data.dat");

            // remove second line

            $targetline = 0;

            foreach ($arr as $line) {

                if (explode(" ", $line)[0] === $fn) {

                    break;

                }

                $targetline = $targetline + 1;

            }
            if ($targetline < count($arr)) { //If found
                unset($arr[$targetline]);
            }

            $arr = array_values($arr);

            file_put_contents("./../assets/movie_data.dat", implode($arr));`