# PHP Removing multiple whole lines from text file

Tags: php

I am using str_replace to remove certain string that starts with the '#' character from a read txt file, however the html output when tested removes only the # symbol. The problem I am having is that I want to remove all of the text beginning with that particular character (including '#' too).

So far I have tried:

**1)**

```
$data = str_replace('#','',file_get_contents($strFileName));
return $data;
```

**2)**

```
fopen($strFileName,'r');
$remove = "#";
$tmpData = file_get_contents($strFileName);
$data = preg_replace("/.*\b" . $remove ."\b.*\n/ui", "#"  , $tmpData);
return $data;
```

The original text file  is like this:

```
#

# bla bla bla 

#

# bla bla bla 

#

# bla bla bla
```

The first try did remove the `#` character but left the rest of the words.
The second didn't work at all.
Thanks.

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/q/28830850/2943403

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do that with `preg_replace`,

```
$data = preg_replace("/^#.*/m", "", $tmpData);
```

Comment: Perfect, many thanks. Any hint on how to remove the line when the comment is indented? For instance the "#comment bla bla" is indented and the above expression does not detect it. Thanks

Comment: Add `\s`: `$data = preg_replace("/^\s*?#.*/m", "", $tmpData);`

Answer (score 1):

You indeed need to use `preg_replace` for replacing the `#`. But you need to "tell" the regex that you are processing a multi-line text, so it wont stop the replacement after the first line. You do that by applying the `m` modifier in the end of the regular expression pattern, so the pattern sent to `preg_replace` will be:

`/^#.*/m` - note the `m` in the end of the expression, which means: **multiline search**

This will match the following: a single `#` char at line start (as `^` is the line start identifier) and all the line afterwards.
With the below replacment:

`$data = preg_replace('/^#.*/m','',$tmpData);`

Will replace the whole lines which were matched above with nothing.

[Here is a working example](https://regex101.com/r/gq7PRh/3).